# Recyclerview is Scrolling when media Player is playing. How can i fix it?

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-recyclerview

I'm developing a ChatApp with the function of Audio Messages. The Recording and playing of this Audio Messages are working very well, but if i click on Play Button the Recyclerview is scrolling up. Anyone have an idea?

Sorry for my bad english, i'm from Germany ;)

AdapterChat.Java

```
private static final int MSG_TYPE_LEFT = 0;
private static final int MSG_TYPE_RIGHT = 1;
Context context;
List<ModelChat> chatList;
String imageUrl;

FirebaseUser fUser;

public AdapterChat(Context context, List<ModelChat> chatList, String imageUrl) {
    this.context = context;
    this.chatList = chatList;
    this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public MyHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    //inflate layouts: row_chat_left.xml for receiver, row_chat_right.xml for sender
    if (i == MSG_TYPE_RIGHT) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row_chat_right, viewGroup, false);
        return new MyHolder(view);
    }
    else {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row_chat_left, viewGroup, false);
        return new MyHolder(view);
    }
}

public void add(ModelChat object) {
    chatList.add(object);
    add(object);
}

@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyHolder myHolder, final int i) {
    final String message = chatList.get(i).getMessage();
    String timeStamp = chatList.get(i).getTimestamp();
    String type = chatList.get(i).getType();

    if (type.equals("text") || message.equals(R.string.message_was_deleted)) {
        //text message
        myHolder.messageTv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        myHolder.messageIv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        myHolder.playAudioBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        myHolder.messageVoiceSb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        myHolder.sbCurrentTime.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        myHolder.sbTotalDuration.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        myHolder.messageTv.setText(message);
    }
    else if (type.equals("audio")) {
        //audio message
        myHolder.messageTv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        myHolder.messageIv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        myHolder.playAudioBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        myHolder.messageVoiceSb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        myHolder.sbCurrentTime.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        myHolder.sbTotalDuration.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        myHolder.voiceMessageUrl = message;

        myHolder.getAdapterPosition();

        myHolder.playAudioBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (myHolder.mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                    myHolder.handler.removeCallbacks(myHolder.updater);
                    myHolder.mediaPlayer.pause();
                    myHolder.playAudioBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play_btn);
                }
                else {
                    myHolder.mediaPlayer.start();
                    myHolder.playAudioBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause_btn);
                    myHolder.updateSeekbar();
                }
            }
        });

        myHolder.prepareMediaPlayer();

        myHolder.messageVoiceSb.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                SeekBar seekBar = (SeekBar) view;
                int playPosition = (myHolder.mediaPlayer.getDuration() / 100) * seekBar.getProgress();
                myHolder.mediaPlayer.seekTo(playPosition);
                myHolder.sbCurrentTime.setText(myHolder.milliSecondsToTimer(myHolder.mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()));
                return false;
            }
        });

        myHolder.mediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(new MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, int i) {
                myHolder.messageVoiceSb.setSecondaryProgress(i);
            }
        });

        myHolder.mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                myHolder.messageVoiceSb.setProgress(0);
                myHolder.playAudioBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play_btn);
                myHolder.mediaPlayer.reset();
                myHolder.prepareMediaPlayer();
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        //image message
        myHolder.messageIv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        myHolder.messageTv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        myHolder.playAudioBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        myHolder.messageVoiceSb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        myHolder.sbCurrentTime.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        myHolder.sbTotalDuration.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        Picasso.get().load(message).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_image_black).into(myHolder.messageIv);
    }

    //set data
    myHolder.messageTv.setText(message);
    myHolder.timeTv.setText(timeStamp);
    try {
        Picasso.get().load(imageUrl).into(myHolder.profileIv);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {

    }

    myHolder.messageLayout.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            //show delete message confirm dialog
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            builder.setTitle(R.string.delete);
            builder.setMessage("Are you sure to delete this message?");
            //delete button
            builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.delete, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    deleteMessage(i);
                }
            });
            //cancel delete button
            builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    //dismiss dialog
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            //create and show dialog
            builder.create().show();
            return false;
        }
    });

    //set seen/delivered status of message
    if (i==chatList.size()-1) {
        if (chatList.get(i).isSeen()) {
            myHolder.isSeenTv.setText("Seen");
        }
        else {
            myHolder.isSeenTv.setText("Delivered");
        }
    }
    else {
        myHolder.isSeenTv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}

private void deleteMessage(int position) {
    final String myUID = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

    /*Logic:
    * Get timeStamp of clicked message
    * Compare the timeStamp of the clicked message with all messages in CHats
    * Where both values matches, delete that message
    * This will allow sender to delete his and receiver's message*/
    String msgTimeStamp = chatList.get(position).getTimestamp();
    final String type = chatList.get(position).getType();
    DatabaseReference dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Chats");
    Query query = dbRef.orderByChild("timestamp").equalTo(msgTimeStamp);
    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                /*if you want to allow sender to delete only his message then
                 * compare sender value with current user's uid
                 * if they match means its the message of sender that is trying to delete*/
                if (ds.child("sender").getValue().equals(myUID)) {
                    if (type.equals("audio")) {
                        HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
                        hashMap.put("type", "text");
                        ds.getRef().updateChildren(hashMap);
                    } else if (type.equals("image")) {
                        HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
                        hashMap.put("type", "text");
                        ds.getRef().updateChildren(hashMap);
                    }
                    /*We can do one of two things here
                     * 1) Remove the message from chats
                     * 2) Set the value of message "This messages was deleted..." */

                    //1) Remove the message from Chats
                    //ds.getRef().removeValue();

                    //2) Set the value of message "This message was deleted..."
                    HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
                    hashMap.put("message", "This message was deleted...");
                    ds.getRef().updateChildren(hashMap);

                    Toast.makeText(context, "message deleted...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "You can delete only your messages...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return chatList.size();
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    //get currently signed in user
    fUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    if (chatList.get(position).getSender().equals(fUser.getUid())) {
        return MSG_TYPE_RIGHT;
    }
    else {
        return MSG_TYPE_LEFT;
    }
}

//view holder class
class MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    //views
    ImageView profileIv, messageIv;
    ImageButton playAudioBtn;
    SeekBar messageVoiceSb;
    TextView messageTv, timeTv, isSeenTv, sbCurrentTime, sbTotalDuration;
    LinearLayout messageLayout; //for click listener to show delete option
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    String voiceMessageUrl = null;

    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    public MyHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        //init views
        profileIv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.profileIv);
        messageIv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.messageIV);
        messageTv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.messageTv);
        messageVoiceSb = itemView.findViewById(R.id.messageVoiceSb);
        playAudioBtn = itemView.findViewById(R.id.playAudioBtn);
        sbCurrentTime = itemView.findViewById(R.id.sbCurrentTime);
        sbTotalDuration = itemView.findViewById(R.id.sbTotalDuration);
        timeTv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.timeTv);
        isSeenTv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.isSeenTv);
        messageLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.messageLayout);

        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

        messageVoiceSb.setMax(100);
    }

    private void prepareMediaPlayer() {
        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(voiceMessageUrl); //url of audio file to play
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
            sbTotalDuration.setText(milliSecondsToTimer(mediaPlayer.getDuration()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(context, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    private Runnable updater = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            updateSeekbar();
            long currentDuration = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
            sbCurrentTime.setText(milliSecondsToTimer(currentDuration));
        }
    };

    private void updateSeekbar() {
        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            messageVoiceSb.setProgress((int) (((float) mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() / mediaPlayer.getDuration()) * 100));
            handler.postDelayed(updater, 1000);
        }
    }

    private String milliSecondsToTimer(long milliSeconds) {
        String timerString = "";
        String secondsString;

        int hours = (int) (milliSeconds / (1000 * 60 * 60));
        int minutes = (int) (milliSeconds % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60);
        int seconds = (int) ((milliSeconds % (1000 * 60 * 60)) % (1000 * 60) / 1000);

        if (hours > 0) {
            timerString = hours + ":";
        }

        if (seconds < 10) {
            secondsString = "0" + seconds;
        } else {
            secondsString = "" + seconds;
        }

        timerString = timerString + minutes + ":" + secondsString;
        return timerString;
    }
}
```

chatActivity.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/chatBackground"
tools:context=".ChatActivity">

<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/profileIv"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_default"
        app:civ_circle_background_color="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp">

        <!-- Receiver Name-->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nameTv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="His Name"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <!-- Receiver Status i.e online or offline-->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/userStatusTv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="online"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/blockIv"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_unblocked_green"
            android:visibility="invisible"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

<!-- RecyclerView-->
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/chat_recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
    android:layout_above="@id/chatLayout" />

<!-- send message edit text and button in layout-->
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/chatLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@color/textInputBackground"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <!-- ImageButton: to send Image-->
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/attachBtn"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_attach_black" />

    <!-- EditText: input message-->
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/messageEt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@null"
        android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:hint="Start typing" />

    <Chronometer
        android:id="@+id/record_timer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />

    <!-- Button: voice message-->
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/recordBtn"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_record_btn_stopped" />

    <!-- Button: send message-->
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/sendBtn"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_send" />
</LinearLayout>
```

row_chat_right.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/messageLayout"
android:padding="10dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="end">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/profileIv"
        app:civ_border_color="@null"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_default_img" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/messageTv"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="@color/textColor"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_sender"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:text="His Message"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/messageIV"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_image_black"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_sender" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_sender"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/playAudioBtn"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_play_btn" />

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/messageVoiceSb"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/playAudioBtn"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:max="100"
            android:progress="0" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sbCurrentTime"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:text="0:00"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/messageVoiceSb"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sbTotalDuration"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="0:10"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_below="@id/messageVoiceSb"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/messageVoiceSb"
            android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/timeTv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="end"
    android:textAlignment="textEnd"
    android:text="07/08/2020 23:00PM"
    android:textColor="@color/textColor"
    android:textSize="12sp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/isSeenTv"
    android:gravity="end"
    android:textAlignment="textEnd"
    android:text="delivered" />
```

Comment: What does this do myHolder.getAdapterPosition();?

Comment: Sorry, i've tested many Things to get it working... It's not neccessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the Fix!!

```
<TextView
android:layout_width="match_parent" <-- This is what I changed
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<SeekBar
android:layout_width="match_parent" <-- Check this as well
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```